# How could I use const in vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I tried to defined a `const` in a `*.vue` file:

```
<script>
    export const CREATE_ACTION = 1,
    export const UPDATE_ACTION = 2
<script>
```

And use them in the template:

```
<template>
    ...
    <select :disabled="mode === UPDATE_ACTION">
    ....
</template>
```

But it does not work. How can I use `const` in a Vue template?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Expose them on your data:

```
new Vue({
    data:{
        CREATE_ACTION: CREATE_ACTION,
        UPDATE_ACTION: UPDATE_ACTION
    }
})
```

Comment: but I want use it in another component,and ... more graceful?

Comment: @litbear you can use mixins or plugins to include things in multiple components, but to reference them in a template, you will have to expose them on data.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that these values get all the Vue interactivity (and associated overhead) by default. Not great, but in small usages it should be ok.

Comment: exposing them to data creates an observable copy of the values. You don't actually comparing to the constant anymore.

Answer (score 71):

If you expose them on your data, you are making them unnecessary reactive, as @mix3d mentioned...

A better approach is to add them into Vue object [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

```
<template>
      <div v-if="action === CREATE_ACTION">Something</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.CREATE_ACTION = CREATE_ACTION;
        this.UPDATE_ACTION = UPDATE_ACTION;
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer in my opinion. Exposing in data makes them reactive and also you still have to use string values in template which we are trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: This has my vote. It can be further elaborated by writing a mixin factory that produces your `created` hook dynamically:
`
function mixinFactory(constants) {
    return {
        created() {
            Object.keys(constants).forEach((cName) => this[cName] = constants[cName]);
        },
    };
}
`

Comment: I like this approach except for the fact that it doesn't seem to play well with TypeScript. Can anyone can suggest a way to eliminate the TS errors here?

Comment: Any way of making these variables into actual constants?

Comment: @Incinerator You could attach these as a [frozen object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze): `this.constants = Object.freeze({ ONE: 1, TWO: 2 })`. To make this work, you add the constants in their own frozen object to an arbitrary key of `this`, rather than to `this` directly.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) for this purpose as you want to include this in multiple components:

```
// constsPlugin.js
const YOUR_CONSTS = {
  CREATE_ACTION: 1,
  UPDATE_ACTION: 2
  ...
}

let YourConsts = {}; // As suggested by the comments.

YourConsts.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.prototype.$getConst = (key) => {
    return YOUR_CONSTS[key]
  }
}

export default YourConsts
```

in **main.js** or where you define `new Vue()`, you have to use it like this:

```
import YourConsts from 'path/to/plugin'

Vue.use(YourConsts)
```

Now you can use this in a component template like following:

```
<div>
   <select :disabled="mode === $getConst('UPDATE_ACTION')">
</div>
```

Comment: I think `YOUR_CONSTS` needs to be in same case as `YourConsts` because I got error that "_YourConsts is not defined_". (ESLint also complains that `YourConsts` is not defined.)

Comment: @GinoMempin, Nope. Its because that variable hasn't been defined. Answer OP should have included, let YourConsts = {} line first before defining install method.

Comment: the author's goal is to get rid of the magic lines, and you offer them to him

Answer (score 11):

What about using Mixins? This is the way I do it. Not sure it is the best or recommended way but the code looks so much cleaner.

**data/actions.js**

```js
export const CREATE_ACTION = 1;
export const UPDATE_ACTION = 2;

export const actionsMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      CREATE_ACTION,
      UPDATE_ACTION
    }      
  }
}
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="action === CREATE_ACTION">Something</div>
</template>

<script>
import {actionsMixin, CREATE_ACTION} from './data/actions.js';

export default {
  mixins: [actionsMixin]
  data() {
    return {
      action: CREATE_ACTION
    }      
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: still creates reactivity overhead for static objects that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Maybe declare it in `created()` stage.

Answer (score 7):

```
<template>
  <div v-if="FOO_CONST.bar">Something</div>
</template>

<script>
import {FOO_CONST} from './const.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      FOO_CONST: Object.freeze(FOO_CONST) // this makes vue not reactive this data property
    }      
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

In Vue 3 you can use [setup()](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html).

Example:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    hello {{ fooConst }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const fooConst = "bar";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      fooConst,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

or fully using the Composition API:

```html
<script setup>
const fooConst = "bar";
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    hello {{ fooConst }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p :style="{ color: $options.COLOR }">
      {{$options.HELLO}} {{$options.PERSON}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const HELLO = 'Hello there.';
const COLOR = 'red';

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('Hello world');
  },
  COLOR,
  HELLO,
  PERSON: 'General Kenobi!',
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. To avoid possible naming conflicts I added an object `const: {COLOR, HELLO, PERSON: 'General Kenobi!}', which can be accessed as `$options.const.HELLO`

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to be a neat way to add constants non-reactively to the vue object.

First create your constants:

```
// Action.js
const Action = {
  CREATE: 1,
  UPDATE: 2
}

Action.Mixin = {
  created () {
    this.Action = Action
  }
}

export default Action
```

Then in the component:

```
<template>
  <select :disabled="mode === Action.UPDATE">
</template>

<script>
import Action from './Action.js'

export default {
  mixins: [Action.Mixin]
}
</script>
```

This is like a cross between Alessandro Benoit's and L. Palaiokostas' answers.

Comment: You still have to make declarations in every component, so not much benefit over other methods.